# how to define a "directed spanning tree"?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, trees

In all my books and articles about "graph theory", I didn't find the definition of "directed spanning tree". Could you please give this definition and the reference?

How to judge if a directed graph is a directed spanning tree?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for an [arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned [arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_%28graph_theory%29) is likely what you are looking for.

A graph is a spanning tree if it is a tree (acyclic, connected graph) that touches each node.

In Directed Spanning trees it looks like either you choose a node, mark it as the root and build a tree that is defined as being a single path from that node to each other node.

Comment: Compared with spanning tree in the undirected graph, the property of "acyclic" and covering all vertices are kept. But "connected" becomes weakly connected instead of strongly connected.