# Questions about spanning forest/ forest

Tags: algorithms, trees

Can I consider it is a forest if there is only one node? For example there is just one node "A" and without any arcs(no arcs) or other node exist.

Comment: If there are no cycles, then it's a forest!

Comment: I have another question if we have this digraph G := ({ 1, 2, 3 }, { (2, 1),(3, 1) }) and I perform a Bread First Search(G, 1) and i got ({ 1 }, ∅) with no arc. Is this a spanning tree or just a tree?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356193/how-to-define-a-directed-spanning-tree/1360491

Comment: So since it does not have all nodes in digraph G, it is not a spanning tree but instead it is just a tree or a forest am I right?